Node.js - Mongoose BSON field 'FindCommandRequest.jsonSchema' is an unknown field
I’m currently working on setting up client-side field level encryption (CSFLE) using Node.js, Express, and Mongoose, following the tutorial for Use Automatic Client-Side Field Level Encryption with AWS. I’ve ensured that all the steps recommended in the tutorial have been followed, and I’m running a MongoDB Enterprise server.
However, when I try to insert a document using the secure client, I encounter the following error:
 Error: MongoServerError: BSON field 'FindCommandRequest.jsonSchema' is an unknown field. This command may be meant for a mongocryptd process.
Has anyone encountered this issue before, or does anyone have insights on how to resolve this error?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
I tried following the tutorial for Use Automatic Client-Side Field Level Encryption with AWS and the documentation from mongoose Mongoose Client Side Field Level Encryption

For the people that have the same problem: somehow i didn't saw that my macbook was preventing to start the mongocryptd service and that was why is was not working.
I also installed the latest drivers as you read it in the documentation for the Client Side Field Level Encryption.
